# Calculation of p-value by ttest_1 samp method

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics, p-value

I decided to go through all the steps of calculating p-value without the ttest_1 samp function. Made calculations according to its source code:

```py
# n = 30
n = len(te)
df = n - 1
d = np.mean(te) - np.mean(mas)
v = np.var(te, ddof=1)
denom = np.sqrt(v / n)
t = np.divide(d, denom)
```

test_1 samp on my sample gave the result

```py
(Ttest_1sampResult(statistical=0.23662123195627474, pvalue=0.8146140812621393)
```

By my calculations, I got a similar t-statistic value, but a different pvalue :

```py
# 0.7684786039713729
pvalue = special.gamma((df+1)/2)/(math.sqrt(df*math.pi)*math.gamma(df/2)) * (1+(t**2/df))**(-(df+1)/2) * 2
```

However, if I remove I change the power of `-(df+1)/2` to `(df+1)/2`,  then p-value is already equal to`0.8142579144560489`

This is already very close, but not accurate. What am I doing wrong?

This is a Student's test for one sample to check the equality of the average sample and the average of the general population. And the ttest_1 samp function from the scipy library

Comment: What is `Ttest_1sampResult` and where does it come from? Please clarify, and add any appropriate tag, in necessary.

Comment: This is a Student's test for one sample to check the equality of the average sample and the average of the general population. And the ttest_1 samp function from the scipy library

Comment: As already said, please **edit & update** your question to clarify this (such info should not be in the comments) and add the relevant `scipy` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the PDF of the t distribution to compute the p-value.  That is not correct. For the two-sided t-test, the p-value is 2*(1 - CDF(t)).  To compute the [CDF of the Student's t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), you can use [`scipy.special.stdtr`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.special.stdtr.html) or `scipy.stats.t.cdf`.  (With `scipy.stats.t`, you can use the `sf()` method to compute `1 - CDF(t)`.)

For example, here's some sample data with a proposed population mean:

```
In [41]: te = [1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2]

In [42]: popmean = 2.5
```

Apply `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp`:

```
In [43]: from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp

In [44]: ttest_1samp(te, popmean)
Out[44]: Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=0.40378642654362384, pvalue=0.6948693123333674)
```

Your t calculation agrees:

```
In [45]: n = len(te)
    ...: df = n - 1
    ...: d = np.mean(te) - popmean
    ...: v = np.var(te, ddof=1)
    ...: denom = np.sqrt(v / n)
    ...: t = np.divide(d, denom)

In [46]: t
Out[46]: 0.40378642654362384
```

Use `scipy.special.stdtr` to compute the p-value:

```
In [47]: from scipy.special import stdtr

In [48]: 2*(1 - stdtr(df, t))
Out[48]: 0.6948693123333674
```

Or use `scipy.stats.t.sf`; I'll call the object `studentst` to avoid overwriting the existing `t` value, and I'll use the `sf()` method to compute 1 - CDF(t):

```
In [52]: from scipy.stats import t as studentst

In [53]: 2*studentst.sf(t, df)
Out[53]: 0.6948693123333674
```